# Calculate proportion of records that match a certain criterion in a Cypher aggregation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine I have a graph which I query like this:

```
MATCH (n:Class)-[:HAS]->(i:Item)
RETURN n.id as Id1, i.id as IdI, i.isWhatever as Criterion
```

getting

```
IdC   IdI  Criterion                                   
  A     1      False
  A     2       True
  B     1       True
```

My desired output would be

```
IdC   ratioCriterion                                   
  A              0.5
  B                1
```

I guess this question boils down to how can I sum a list of booleans in cypher. The part of dividing by the size of the aggregation is easy. I mean that the complete query would look like:

```
MATCH (n:Class)-[:HAS]->(i:Item)
WITH n.id as Id1, count_number_of_True_values / count(*) as ratioCriterion
```

But I just don't know how to write the `count_number_of_True_values` bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching is this query :

```
MATCH (n:Class)-[:HAS]->(i:Item)
WITH n.id as Id1, i.id as IdI, i.isWhatever as Criterion
WITH Id1, CASE WHEN Criterion  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS numCrit
WITH Id1, collect(numCrit) AS crits
RETURN Id1, reduce(s = 0, x IN crits | s + x)/toFloat(size(crits))
```

I do a lot of `WITH` to show you the different steps.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess that for readability I would just remove the second line and write the second like this: `WITH n.id as Id1, CASE WHEN i.isWhatever  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS numCrit`.